# Jmeter - Regular Expression to extract the 7 digits from the response

Tags: regex-group

I would like to extract the POS_ID - 7 digit number from the response below. When I see the value of the variable using debug sampler I am seeing Error stored

Reponse:

> ~am_ct_AccountType_wca_DEBIT_OWNERSHIP_CODE#*#-1~|~am_ct_AccountType_wca_FEE_PCKG_NAME#*#~|~am_ct_AccountType_wca_POS_ID#*#9004910

I tried with all the below expression

1. am_ct_AccountType_wca_POS_ID([0-9]{7}) - Error is getting stored in variable
2. am_ct_AccountType_wca_POS_ID#*#([0-9]{7}) - Error is getting stored in variable
3. ([0-9]{7}) - From the response got the 1st occurrence of 7 digits from the response.

That is not what I want.

```
Match No.: 1
Default Value: Error
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this "POS_ID#*#(.+)" as the value of the regular expression field and "**$1$**" for the template field and "**1**" for match No.
make sure you use a "\" before the * in the regular exp

Comment: Thank you. The mistake what I made is I did not use '\' before the *. This worked now.